# Blazor Grid Bound Column by Field Name

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm studying some paid grid components and they have a pretty cool "Bound Column" technique:

```
<TelerikGrid Data=@GridData>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="TemperatureC" Title="Temp. C" />
        <GridColumn Field="Summary" />
    </GridColumns>
    <GridToolBar>
        <GridCommandButton Command="Add" Icon="add">Add Forecast</GridCommandButton>
    </GridToolBar>
</TelerikGrid>

<DxDataGrid Data="@DataSource">
    <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(ProductFlat.Id)">
    </DxDataGridColumn>
    <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(ProductFlat.Category)">
    </DxDataGridColumn>
</DxDataGrid>
```

how can I achieve this? I want to create a very basic table:

```
<MyGrid DataSource=@MySource>
  <MyColumn Field="Id" Name="My Id" />
</MyGrid>
```

to render:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">My Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>#1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A clue : use reflection

Comment: @aguafrommars, yes, it's a mix of Reflection, CascadingValue, Lifecycle methods and dynamic RenderFragments :)

Comment: @daniherrera I was to lazy to provide a full solution :D

Comment: @aguafrommars, Yes, I also waited a few for an answer ... but it was an interesting exercise.

Comment: Sure, reflection is the way to go, but! How to reverse engineer  the child content to array of MyColumn? I need it to create the grid header

Comment: @Alexandre, no reverse engineer needed, just notify about child existence to outer component sending parent via CascadingValue. Was a funny challenge. Full code on my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a trivial solution, you should to understand how Blazor works with components. Basically, the way, is to register children `MyColumn` "templates" on outer `MyGrid` component, then, render grid dynamically with a bit of reflection. Below I post the recipe ready for copy-paste, test and learn.

### Step 0: Create the templated blazor demo:

```
dotnet new blazorserver
```

### Step 1: Create `Pages/MyColumn.razor` component:

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    private MyGrid Parent { get; set; }    

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();        
        Parent.AddColumn(this); //register child into parent
    }
}
```

### Step 2: Create `Pages/MyGrid.razor` component:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @ChildContent
        @foreach (var item in DataSource)
        {
            @RowItem(item) 
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<object> DataSource { get; set; }

    List<MyColumn> Columns = new List<MyColumn>();
    public void AddColumn(MyColumn column)
    {
        Columns.Add(column);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

`// Here the function to create each row dynamically:`

```
    private RenderFragment RowItem(object row)
    {   
        int i = 0;
        return b =>          // create dynamically
        {
            b.OpenElement(++i, "tr");
            foreach(var column in Columns)
            {
                b.OpenElement(++i, "td");
                var val = row.GetType().GetProperty(column.Field)
                          .GetValue(row, null).ToString();                
                b.AddContent(++i,val);
                b.CloseElement();
            }
            b.CloseElement();
        };
    }
}
```

### Step 3: Use your grid on `Pages/FetchData.razor`

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using s.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <MyGrid DataSource=@forecasts>
       <MyColumn Field="Date"/>
       <MyColumn Field="Summary"/>
    </MyGrid>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Good job! More background: Creating Blazor Templated Components http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4339/Creating-Blazor-Templated-Components.aspx

Comment: I am trying to implement this binding and I was wondering on how can I push data from SignalR Hub to this? Let's suppose I have stock prices, volume that change every second. I want all users (multiple browser windows) to see the same data.