# How to implement DataGrid component in server-side Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to create a DataGrid component in Blazor that can be used like the following in a Razor component page. Someone asked the same question on the Blazor GitHub issue tracker at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14886. I tried using the code that is listed there, but, found that the columns aren't added to the DataTable until after the code at the top runs. As a result, none of the columns are rendered. I'm thinking that the person who posted the example code may have been using client-side Blazor (WebAssembly). That's the only reason I can think of that it would work for them, but, not me.

My question is, what is the recommended approach to creating complex UI components in Blazor? I think part of the problem here is that the DataTableColumn is a component. However, it is not intended to actually be rendered. It is just being used as configuration/parameter data for DataTable which does the actual rendering. So, I am wondering if this is kind of an abuse of the design of Blazor. Telerik and other companies do this though. https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/grid/overview

Index.razor

```
@page "/users"

@using FolioLibrary

<fieldset>
    <legend>Users</legend>

    <DataTable Class="table" Data="@(folioContext.User2s.Take(10).Cast<dynamic>().ToList())">
        <DataTableColumn Name="Id" Field="Id" Type="typeof(Guid)"></DataTableColumn>
        <DataTableColumn Name="Name" Field="Name" Type="typeof(string)"></DataTableColumn>
        <DataTableColumn>
            <Template Context="item">
                <a href="/@item.Id" class="btn">text</a>
            </Template>
        </DataTableColumn>
    </DataTable>

@code
{
    private FolioContext folioContext = new FolioContext();
}
```

DataTable.razor

```
<div class="col-12">
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
        <table class="@Class" id="@Id">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @ChildContent
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @*@foreach (dynamic item in FilteredData.Skip((Page - 1) * PerPage).Take(PerPage))*@
                @foreach (dynamic item in Data)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataTableColumn column in Columns)
                        {
                            <td class="align-middle" width="@(column.Type == null ? "1%" : "")">
                                @if (column.Template is null)
                                {
                                    @item.GetType().GetProperty(column.Field).GetValue(item, null)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @column.Template(item)
                                }
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </CascadingValue>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<dynamic> Data
    {
        get => data;
        set
        {
            data = value;
            FilteredData = data;
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public int PerPage { get; set; } = 25;

    [Parameter]
    public int Page { get; set; } = 1;

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<dynamic> Actions { get; set; }

    List<DataTableColumn> Columns { get; set; } = new List<DataTableColumn>();

    List<dynamic> FilteredData { get; set; }

    List<dynamic> data;

    public void AddColumn(DataTableColumn column)
    {
        Columns.Add(column);
    }

    public void RemoveColumn(DataTableColumn column)
    {
        Columns.Remove(column);
    }
}
```

DataTableColumn.razor

```
@implements IDisposable

<th>
    <span>@Name</span>
</th>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<dynamic> Template { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    DataTable DataTable { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DataTable.AddColumn(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DataTable.RemoveColumn(this);
    }

}
```

I temporarily added `OnInitialized()` and `OnAfterRender()` methods to see what order the components are being created in and when the events are raised and the following was the order.

```
DataTable.OnInitialized
DataTableColumn.OnInitialized
DataTable.OnInitialized
DataTableColumn.OnInitialized
DataTable.OnAfterRender
DataTableColumn.OnAfterRender
```

I was thinking maybe I could use some other event/method to make it render later, but, the rendering code/foreach loops are in the main body of the Razor component, not in a call back method.

Before trying this, I had a simpler grid component with a HeaderTemplate and an ItemTemplate. However, I need something more complex, because I want to build in sort functionality where you can click on the column heading and have the grid component do the sort for you.

Comment: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257463/842935

Comment: Thanks Dani. That gets me further along. There is another problem that I'm running into now though. The problem is that DataSource is getting set 4 times over on a page load. I'm setting DataSource to a LINQ to Entities query expression. So, it is executing the database query 4 times over. Maybe I could do the query in OnInitialize(), but, I think even that gets called more than once. And I need it to be a query expression, not an array, because I need the ability to have the grid change the sort order and filter.

Comment: Hi mr Jon, this is because each `AddColumn` raises `StateHasChanged();`. You can use a kind of 'cache' to store the `IEnumerable` and read from 'cache' instead from `[Parameter]` (to don't execute the query again and again). When I say a 'cache' I mean just a var where to store values.

Comment: @daniherrera I can't do that, because I want the grid to be able to modify the LINQ expression tree to add a .Where() method based on what a user enters into text boxes that I'm going to put in the column headings. I'm wondering if there is a way to only call StateHasChanged() after the last column has been added.

Comment: You can identify when a column is added and, just in this case, if dataset is already loaded, don't execute query again. It is not like this?

Comment: @daniherrera I found out what it was. The component executes twice. Once, normally, and I'm assuming once for the StateHasChanged() call. However, I did find that though, StateHasChanged() was called more than once, those calls appeared to be folded into one. The foreach loop in the main body code was executing twice, once when the Columns collection was empty and once after it was populated. So, I added an if (Columns.Any()) so that it only enumerates DataSource when there are columns. Secondly, I found that when you directly access the component by URL in the browser it repeats everything.

Comment: Hi @Jon, I talk about this: https://gist.github.com/ctrl-alt-d/dc6d0472c67776d07a5cac324e90310e

Comment: _The component executes twice._ this behavior can be because pre-render: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696602/842935

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks for the info. Regarding the cache, I'm confused as to why you would do that. You are converting the DataSource enumerable to a List each time you add a column. That would actually make things worse. Note, I am storing the query as an IQueryable<T>, not a List<T> or IEnumerable<T>. This is because I'm going to have text boxes in the heading of each column that will allow the grid to modify the IQueryable<T> and add a .Where().