# Blazor components can they be processed as natural parent children in xml?

Tags: c#, components, blazor

Is there any intention in the future with Blazor to support a more natural component model in XML where you can declare components with parents and children as below:

```
<RadioGroup TItem="TestModel.TestEnum"
        @bind-Value="@TestModel.Field5"
        InlineLayout="@InlineLayout"
        ValidationFor="@(() => TestModel.Field5)"
        Label="RadioGroup Field 5 Horizontal">

            <RadioItem Id="Enum1" Label="Enum 1" SelectedValue="TestModel.TestEnum.Enum1" />
            <RadioItem Id="Enum2" Label="Enum 2" SelectedValue="TestModel.TestEnum.Enum2" />
            <RadioItem Id="Enum3" Label="Enum 3" SelectedValue="TestModel.TestEnum.Enum3" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

I would like RadioGroup to be the parent of a collection of RadioItems. Each RadioItem would contain info on a radio button. I would like to add the RadioItems to RadioGroup and then from RadioGroup render each of the RadioItems as radio buttons.

However, it seems that the items are added to the collection after it attempts to loop around the collection of items.

This code in the parent is executed before OnInitialized in RadioItem.razor is called

RadioGroup.razor:

```
@foreach (RadioItem<TItem> item in Items)
{
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Label))
    {
        <InputRadio Id="@item.Id" Label="@item.Label" SelectedValue="@item.SelectedValue" @bind-Value="@CurrentValue" />
    }                    
}
```

RadioItem.razor:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public RadioGroup<TItem> Parent { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Parent.AddChild(this);
}
```

Is there some way of adding items to the parent collection before RadioGroup attempts to render the collection of RadioItems?

Comment: Is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255581/blazor-grid-bound-column-by-field-name/59257463#59257463 (but with grid/column instead radioGrouo/radioItem )

Comment: Thanks dani herrera for that link it did the job: I had most of the code: was just missing StateHasChanged() in my equivalent of AddColumn(). Much appreciated